# Need help with delegate call or other possible solutions to get ownership of a contract

Tags: delegatecall

So I'm in a bit of a situation. Here's a short description of it:

1. SmartContractA is a staking contract which is owned by SmartContractB
2. SmartContractB has wrong address of smartContractA in its struct so it's not able to call any functions of smartContractA
3. SmartContractB is owned by a wallet which I control.

I need to access smartContractA's transferOwnership function which can be only called by owner (smartContractB). The way I see it is there could be two possible options:

(I) Doing a delegate call to smartContractA from a new contract (smartContractC?) via SmartContractB such that the msg.sender that goes to smartContractA is smartContractB.
(II) SmartContractB has a function which allows changing of the owner of smartContractA, however since it does not know the correct address of smartContractA it's not working. If I can somehow make a delegate call to update the struct to make that call?

Am I thinking in the right direction? Would really appreciate your help here.

Comment: I only see two possibilities. ContractB can execute delegatecall to ContractC, or contractB can execute call to any contract.